# Two foreign key fields, exactly one is set to a value, the other null in django model with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, conditional-statements

I have a django model with two foreign key fields, one that points to product, the other points to portfolio in the code below. Exatcly one of these should be set for each Lca record. I know I can do this with MySQL triggers, but I was wondering if there was a way to make this conditional save in django

```
class Lca(models.Model):
    product             = models.ForeignKey(product, null=True, blank=True)
    portfolio           = models.ForeignKey(portfolio, null=True, blank=True)
    carbon_price        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    total_footprint     = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    calculation_type    = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    total_cv            = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    source              = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    date_from           = models.DateField()
    date_to             = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    # end __unicode__
# end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) the model's [`save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.product and self.portfolio or not self.product and not self.portfolio:
        raise ValueError('Exactly one of [Lca.product, Lca.portfolio] must be set')

    super(Lca, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that this method is not applicable to [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clean forms validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) if you requested your data from a form.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a model `clean()` method for any custom validation you want to add. Model clean methods are called automatically by ModelForms, but not by save(), so you may need to call the model `full_clean()` method yourself and handle ValidationErrors if they occur, depending on your use case.

See the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) for more information on `Model.clean()`.